# How do panel regression estimates differ from those obtained from multiple time series regressions?

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data

I am trying to familiarise myself with panel regression techniques and I would like to know how the parameter estimates obtained from a panel regression model differ from those obtained from multiple time series regressions. Are they ever the same under specific assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not an expert in time series methods, so take this with a grain of salt.)  But if you fit a number of series separately, it should be like fitting fixed effects in a larger model.  Whereas panel regression would have a random effect distribution that would 'borrow' information from other series to inform what a given series is doing.  If we set the time series aspect aside, I cover these ideas in more detail in my answer here: [Why do the estimated values from a Best Linear Unbiased Predictor (BLUP) differ from a Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122587/7290)